# onAuthRequired triggering only once in Chrome version > 72

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, basic-authentication

In our project we are using Selenium to test our Angular Web Application using a docker image and chrome with version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit). Since the application uses basic authentication on our servers we created our own extension to listen to "onAuthRequired" and whenever this happens we return the username and password ([Original Source](https://devopsqa.wordpress.com/2018/08/05/handle-basic-authentication-in-selenium-for-chrome-browser/)).

A simple test for our application would be to navigate to the main page (basic auth login required with the popup window) and then to another subpage that is hosted inside of this page in an iframe where the basic authentication is required again.

We added some logging to the extension just to check whether the onAuthRequired gets triggered so the extension currently looks like this:

```
​if (!chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.hasListener(retrieveCredentials)) {
  chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    retrieveCredentials,
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ['blocking']
  );
}

function retrieveCredentials(details) {
  console.log("onAuthRequired");
  return {
    authCredentials: {
      username: username,
      password: password
  }
  };
}
```

What we found out is that with the Version 72.0.3626 this was still working. The extension would fill out both of the login prompts that occur and we would see two messages with "onAuthRequired" in the console.

However with the Version 73.0.3683 and newer, this seems to not work anymore. Only one time the onAuthRequired (retrieveCredentials-Method) is called and the second popup gets ignored by the extension. This lets the Selenium tests fail with a timeout exception since the navigation doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know how to handle this in the newer Versions of Chrome or sees a mistake that we made in our extension?

Any help appreciated